# Comma inside MySQL query

Tags: php, mysql

```
$sql_query_posts = "SELECT * FROM `posts`";

$sql_form_permission = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `integrations` WHERE `rank_id`='$user_level' AND `mode`='form_per'");
    if ( mysql_num_rows($sql_form_permissions) > 0 ) {
```

Now the part I'm struggling with:

```
   $sql_query_posts .= " IN (";
    while ( $row_form_permissions = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql_form_permissions) ) { 
    $sql_query_posts .= $row_form_permissions['form_id'] . ",";
    }
    $sql_query_posts .= ")";
    }
```

I want the output to be something like:

```
SELECT * FROM `posts` IN (4, 3, 2)
```

But the code above gives an output like:

```
SELECT * FROM `posts` IN (4, 3, 2,)
```

So I have to get rid of the comma at the end. How can I make sure the script disables the comma at the last row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `$sql_query_posts = substr($sql_query_posts, 0, -1);` like this:

```
$sql_query_posts .= " IN (";
while ( $row_form_permissions = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql_form_permissions) ) { 
    $sql_query_posts .= $row_form_permissions['form_id'] . ",";
}
$sql_query_posts = substr($sql_query_posts, 0, -1);
$sql_query_posts .= ")";
```

Just to address the case when you might end up with no records fetched (an empty array), it would maybe be wiser to use implode(), like this (I always use it like that):

```
$ins = array();
while ( $row_form_permissions = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql_form_permissions) ) {
    $ins[] = $row_form_permissions['form_id'];
}
$sql_query_posts .= sprintf(' IN (%s)', implode(',', $ins));
```

Comment: What if no record was fetched?

Comment: I agree that at least a check should be made for empty result set and I updated the answer accordingly, using implode().

Answer (score 4):

I would use `implode` for that:

```
$post_ids = array();
while ( $row_form_permissions = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql_form_permissions) ) { 
    $post_ids[] = $row_form_permissions['form_id'];
}

$sql_query_posts .= " IN (" . implode(",", $post_ids) . ")";
```

Comment: I just saw that you posted your answer before MaX, so I'll comment on this one also. I agree implode() should be used rather than substring(), but the question was asked in such a way that it seemed like substring() was what was asked for. I upvoted your answer to reflect the importance of using implode() over substr() or trim().

Answer (score 2):

A prettier way, in my opinion, than the suggested is:

```
$forms = array();
while ( $row_form_permissions = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql_form_permissions) )
  $forms[] = $row_form_permissions['form_id'];

$sql_query_posts .= " IN (".implode(",",$forms).")";
```

Comment: I agree implode() should be used rather than substring(), but the question was asked in such a way that it seemed like substring() was what was asked for. I upvoted your answer to reflect the importance of using implode() over substr() or trim().

Answer (score 0):

You could just use `substr` to get the comma off. Like this:

```
$sql_query_posts .= " IN (";
while ( $row_form_permissions = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql_form_permissions) ) { 
$sql_query_posts .= $row_form_permissions['form_id'] . ",";
}
$sql_query_posts = substr($sql_query_posts, 0, -1); // <- this is the new line
$sql_query_posts .= ")";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As an alternate to `substr` you can also use `trim` to get rid of the comma.

```
$sql_query_posts = trim($sql_query_posts, ',') . ')';
```

Trim is slightly safer than substr because you can limit it to an exact character or set of characters.

Answer (score 0):

I would use trim or (rtrim) function is such situations (http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php)
You give the string to it, and specify the extra character using its second parameter and it cleans it up for you.